# How can I calculate the average of values between the 20th and 80th percentile?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following SQL query in Google's BigQuery:

```
SELECT
  sensor,
  date,
  time,
  perc,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(perc,
    0.2) OVER(PARTITION BY sensor, date) AS percentile20_day,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(perc,
    0.8) OVER(PARTITION BY sensor, date) AS percentile80_day
FROM
  sensordata
ORDER BY
  Sensor,
  date,
  time
```

Now, one additional calculation that I want to add is the average between two percentiles. In this specific case, the average of all the values between the 20th and 80th percentile for the entire day. I don't want to be limited to the day though and potentially change it to a time window (by adding a further partition, for example).

So far, I was not able to get this done. I am failing to understand how I could add this.

Comment: Seems, you have to get values between 20th and 80th percentile to be able to get average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT sensor, date, time, perc, percentile20_day, percentile80_day,
       AVG(CASE WHEN perc >= percentile20_day AND perc <= percentile90_day THEN perc END) OVER () as avg_20_80,
FROM (SELECT sd.*
            PERCENTILE_CONT(perc, 0.2) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor, date) AS percentile20_day,
            PERCENTILE_CONT(perc, 0.8) OVER (PARTITION BY sensor, date) AS percentile80_day
      FROM sensordata sd
     ) sd
ORDER BY Sensor, date, time;
```

Comment: Thanks, should be `<=percentile80_day` though, plus an `END` at the end of the case statement.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT sensor, `date`, AVG(perc) avg_percentile20_80_day
FROM (
  SELECT sensor, `date`, perc,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(perc, 0.2) OVER(PARTITION BY sensor, `date`) percentile20_day,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(perc, 0.8) OVER(PARTITION BY sensor, `date`) percentile80_day
  FROM `project.dataset.sensordata`
)
WHERE perc BETWEEN percentile20_day AND percentile80_day
GROUP BY sensor, `date`
```

Comment: The downside of this approach would be to not have several time frames in one query, but having to run multiple queries.

Comment: I think I agree with you :o) I less focused on that aspect of your question and was more focused on getting proper solution for the main part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT date, AVG(CASE
    WHEN sensor < PERCENTILE_CONT(perc, 0.2) OVER(PARTITION BY sensor, date) THEN NULL
    WHEN sensor > PERCENTILE_CONT(perc, 0.8) OVER(PARTITION BY sensor, date) THEN NULL
    ELSE sensor
    ) AS AvgSensorBTW20thAnd80thPercentile
FROM sensordata
GROUP BY date
```

Note: not tested!

According to MSDN documentation [AVG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function ignores `NULL`s.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. The `AVG` function doesn't allow the analysis functions like `PERCENTILE_CONT`.